# What is the difference between a function and a curve?

Tags: functions, curves

Are all curves functions? To my current knowledge a function gives only one output for a given input so x->f(x) , but for example a circle which is a curve is "made" out of two functions, so generally speaking a circle is a curve yet not a function, so can someone provide me a good distinction between them and good definition of a curve. Thanks!

Comment: In absolute generality, a curve in the plane is probably just any subset of the plane. But we usually think of a curve in the plane as a set of points $(f(t),g(t))$ where $f$ and $g$ are nice functions and $t$ takes on all values from an interval. The graph of a nice function $g$ is the special case where $f (t)=t $.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that the most general definition of ''curve''  that correspond to our intuition is:

> A curve is a continuous function $\gamma: I \to X$ where $ I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an *interval* and $X$ is a topological space.

So, every curve is a function, but this does not means that, If $X= \mathbb{R}^2$ than any curve can be expressed as a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \qquad y=f(x)$.

In this case, as you notice, a circle is a curve, but we have not a single function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ such that the points of the circle are the graph of $f$.

But note that these points $P=(x,y)$ on the circle can be represented as the domain of a function $f:[0,2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ as  $f(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$.

Answer (score 3):

Given two spaces, $X$ and $Y$, a function $f$ is a relation from $X$ to $Y$ such that there exists exactly one $y\in Y$ for every $x\in X$ such that $(x,y)\in f$.  Written another way, $f(x)=y$.  If $f(x)=y_1$ and $f(x)=y_2$ then $y_1=y_2$.

In terms of our usual functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the above condition says that it should pass "the vertical line test."  If we were to take a pencil, and move the pencil from left to right perpendicular to the $x$ axis, at each point in time it will cross the graph of the function at exactly one point. (no more than one and no fewer than one).

Curves on the other hand are more general.  Most (*if not all*) curves can be defined as a function from $[0,1]$ to $X\times Y$ (*at least these are the only useful curves in my opinion*).  $f(t)=(f_1(t),f_2(t))$.  For example, the unit circle can be described by the curve $f(t)=(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$.

Often-times we can choose to ignore what values of $t$ generate the specific outputs and refer simply to the image of such a function as the curve.

In this definition, we do not disallow there to be $x$ values which have multiple $y$ values associated with it.  I.e. it might fail the vertical line test.

Special types of curves exist such as closed curves (when $f(0)=f(1)$), simple curves (when $f(t_1)\neq f(t_2)$ for all $t_1\neq t_2$), etc...

[Read more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve).

Comment: A curve doesn't necessarily have to be a parametrization, does it?

Answer (score 3):

- A curve is a graphical representation of the relation between two (or more) variables (an equation), where for each $x$ there may be multiple $y$. For example, you can make a curve of the unitcircle by the equation $x^2+y^2=1$
- A function is a subset of the family of curves with the restriction that for each $x$ there is exactly one $y$ (or ($f(x)$). If you want to represent a circle in that case you need to combine $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Notice that the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ cannot be simplified in a function by expressing $y$ as a function of $x$ since for each $-1<x<1$ there are two values for $y$.

Answer (score 2):

A curve does not always have one or fewer values for each argument, which is the primary condition for a function. We can say that a curve is a **continuous relation,** which may not have at most one value of $y$ for each value of $x.$ One thing is for sure, though - a function is more clearly defined than a curve.

Comment: So all the functions are $1-1$......Edit please. Regards.